# How to add a Link on top of my video in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-selectors

So I have added a video on my react page with some custom css.I want to add a link on top of the video but it is not getting added.When I reload my page I can see the link for a split of a second.Here is my code.

React code

```
import tsquare from '../mediafiles/tsquare.mp4'
import "./TimesSquare.css";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
function TimesSquare(){
    return(
        <>
     <div class="video-container">
    <video autoPlay muted loop id="myVideo">
        <source  src={tsquare} type="video/mp4"/> 
     
     </video>
     <Link className="explore" to="/home">Tour</Link>
     </div>
   
  
     </>
    )
}
export default TimesSquare;
```

Css code

```
.video-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .video-container video {
    /* Make video to at least 100% wide and tall */
    min-width: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%; 
    
    /* Setting width & height to auto prevents the browser from stretching or squishing the video */
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    
    /* Center the video */
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  }
```

Comment: Have you already tried to add z-index to your Link?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `z-index` property to your link **or** add your `<link>` before the video.

```
.explore {
   z-index: 2;
}
```

```css
.video-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    
    /* if you want to center the container, you can do this */
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  
  .video-container video {
    border: 1px solid purple;
  }
  
  a {
    position: absolute;
    left: 12px;
    top: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="video-container">
  <a className="explore" href="#">Tour</a>
  <video>
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos.
  </video>

</div>
```

Also keep in mind that when you position something 'absolute', it will set to a parent reference container. You can add `position:relative` to the container you want to use as a reference.

Comment: Reference container should not be set to `position: relative`, it should be not `static`, which is default value for position. Which means, position `absolute` or `fixed` etc. will do the trick also. Author has `position: absolute` on his container. Also, your solution with just z-index will not work, link should also be not `static` (`position: relative` work fine)

Comment: @VladislavAkhmetvaliyev It's true that you don't 'have' to set that position relative. But it's generally recommended so you have an idea what your absolute position it is relative to. I have changed my answer a bit.

Comment: you are wrong. There are no any recommendations to set position to relative. An element with [position absolute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#absolute) is **positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor, if any**; otherwise, it is placed relative to the initial containing block. A positioned element is **an element whose computed position value is either relative, absolute, fixed, or sticky**. (In other words, it's anything except static.). So, if an author has already used position absolute on .video-container it's totally fine

Comment: I thought 'relative' was the default, so I learned that today. His example doesn't have any parent container set to any other position (as far as we can see), so i'd still argue it's recommended to keep elements in the normal document flow, if it's not really required to take it out.